# Simple if inside an each scss

Tags: sass

I've just started my scss experience and I'm trying to figure out why this kind of code it's not respond like I want.

```
@each $key,
$par in (a:1, b:0, c:1) {
  @if #{$par}==1 {
    .#{$key} {
      color:red
    }
  }
}
```

I'm trying to create a class only if the $par element of the map is equal to 1. 
I'm preety sure that I'm stucking in some logical easy step, but searching around have found nothing about this simple example.
[my_codepen](http://codepen.io/9i0xin9/pen/LxVNEJ)

Answer (score 2):

Lose the interpolation in the if-statement and you're good.

```
@each $key, $par in (a:1, b:0, c:1) {
    @if ($par == 1) {
        .#{$key} {
            color:red
          }
    }
}
```